# Remove lines having older end time

Tags: bash

In my bash script I want to add a code which remove all entries older than x days.

1. To simplify this problem, I have divided into 3 parts. 2 parts are
   done looking answer for 3rd part.)
   a) To find the latest log date - Done
   b) evaluate earliest epoch time. (All entries before this epoch
   time should be deleted) - Done

> No_OF_DAYS=2
>
> One_Day=86400000
>
> ```
> Latest_Time=`find . -name '*.tps' -exec sed '/endTime/!d; s/{//; s/,.*//' {} + | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d: -f2`  #latest epoch time
> Days_in_Epoch=$(($One_Day * $No_OF_DAYS))
> Earliest_Time=$((Latest_Time - $Days_in_Epoch)) #earliest epoch time
> ```

c) delete all log entries older than evaluated earliest time.

PS:

1. there are multiple files and distributed in different sub folders.
2. All files having extension as `".tps"`.
3. time is in epoch format. endTime will be considered for calculations.(`"endTime"`:`1488902735220`)
4. sample data

Code:

```
{"endTime":1488902734775,"startTime":1488902734775,"operationIdentity":"publishCacheStatistics","name":"murex.risk.control.excesses.cache.CacheStatisticsTracer","context":{"parentContext":{"id":-1,"parentContext":null},"data":[{"value":"excessCacheExcessKeysToContexts","key":"name"},{"value":"0","key":"hits"},{"value":"0","key":"misses"},{"value":"0","key":"count"},{"value":"0","key":"maxElements"},{"value":"0","key":"evictions"},{"value":"N/A","key":"policy"}],"id":0}}
{"endTime":1488902735220,"startTime":1488902735220,"operationIdentity":"publishCacheStatistics","name":"murex.risk.control.excesses.cache.CacheStatisticsTracer","context":{"parentContext":{"id":-1,"parentContext":null},"data":[{"value":"excessCacheExcessKeysToContexts","key":"name"},{"value":"0","key":"hits"},{"value":"0","key":"misses"},{"value":"0","key":"count"},{"value":"0","key":"maxElements"},{"value":"0","key":"evictions"},{"value":"N/A","key":"policy"}],"id":8}}
{"endTime":1488902735550,"startTime":1488902735550,"operationIdentity":"publishCacheStatistics","name":"murex.risk.control.excesses.cache.CacheStatisticsTracer","context":{"parentContext":{"id":-1,"parentContext":null},"data":[{"value":"excessCacheContextsToExcessIds","key":"name"},{"value":"0","key":"hits"},{"value":"0","key":"misses"},{"value":"0","key":"count"},{"value":"0","key":"maxElements"},{"value":"0","key":"evictions"},{"value":"N/A","key":"policy"}],"id":9}}
```

For Example:

a)

> latest epoch time = 1488902735550

b)

> earliest epoch time = 1488902735220

Problem: Now I am looking for command which delete all the entries which is older/lesses than earliest epoch time. In above example 1st line should be deleted.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated. Thank you Linux

Comment: Note that the data you're handling is JSON, and that it might help to parse it as such rather than using text-manipulation tools. `jq` is an handy tool for parsing JSON from bash

Comment: Heh, I told him that on his last question.

Comment: @ankit, you need to use a language like awk or perl or python, where you can filter lines based on an arithmetic condition. sed's not built for that.

Comment: Thanks guys for replying. I am not specifically looking in sed command. I think i can use awk in bash script. The problem is I can't use other tools as this is a small part of my bash script. So there is no other way to implement it in bash script ??

Comment: The main problem with using text-manipulation tool is that your solution might break as soon as the data format changes. The second problem is that at equivalent levels of knowledge, someone using the JSON parser will be much more productive than someone using text-manipulation tools. Of course you have to learn to use the JSON tool first, but that really hardly takes more than 30 min to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick buddy. Be careful to test it with backup files first as it will overwrite your logs directly. Also change the TIME variable for whatever you want to compare.

```
while read file 
do

    awk -v FS=':|,' -v TIME='1488902735220' '{ if (! ($2 > TIME) && !( $0 ~ /^ *$/ ) )  { print $0 }   }'  $file > tmp.txt && cat tmp.txt > $file


done < <( find ./ -name '*.tps' 2>/dev/null )
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current solution, I'd use a simple loop to read the file line by line and only output those whose endTime is greater than your earliest time :

```
while read line; do
    line_endTime=$(awk -F '[:,]' '{print $2}' <<< $line)
    if [ "$line_endTime" -le "$Earliest_Time" ]; then echo $line; fi
done < input_file > filtered_output_file
```